# How do I put a $_POST value(searcing after users) in a SESSION?

Tags: php, mysql

I am making a search service on my page so the users are able to search for other users. 
I want to put the $_POST value in a SESSION and use the SESSION value in a SELECT for the search.
This is what ive done, but it doesnt work - Seems like the SESSION doesnt have any value at all, but im not sure?

```
session_start();
include_once 'dbconnect.php';

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

  $search = $con->real_escape_string($_POST['search']);

  $_SESSION['test'] = $search;
  $test =  $_SESSION['test'];

  $result="SELECT * FROM users WHERE username LIKE '%$test%'";

  ...
```

Comment: do you actually execute the sql query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make sure you start your session with

```
session_start();
```

before you try to access the `$_SESSION` variables and make sure the database you're connect to with `$con` is set properly.

Comment: $con works without any problem. If i dont use the SESSION, the search work

Comment: What do you get if you echo `$_SESSION['test']` after setting it? Is there any notice or warning being thrown?

Comment: Ahh thnks!. im so dumb. i found the problem due to the echo xD